# Get Form Post Response Body in WKWebView DecidePolicy

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am using Xamarin.iOS for developing an iOS app and have implemented the the DecidePolicy of WKNavigationDelegate if my webview as below:

```
        public override void DecidePolicy(WKWebView webView, WKNavigationResponse navigationResponse, Action<WKNavigationResponsePolicy> decisionHandler)
    {
        if (webView.Url.AbsoluteString == @"www.myurl.com")
        {
            var response = navigationResponse.Response as NSHttpUrlResponse;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(response.ToString());

        }
        decisionHandler?.Invoke(WKNavigationResponsePolicy.Allow);
    }
```

There's a button on this page that when clicked calls a form "POST". This in turn submits the form and return an HTTP Status 200 along with only hidden elements in the response form body. I want to retrieve these hidden elements for further processing in my app.

My problem is two parts:

1. The response object above only contains the header responses and I need to get the body of the response
2. I don't actually know when using the overridden DecidePolicy(..) from above whether the form has been submitted on that url? I can achieve that by using the other DecidePolicy:

   ```
   public override void DecidePolicy(WKWebView webView, WKNavigationAction navigationAction, Action<WKNavigationActionPolicy>decisionHandler) 
   {
       if (navigationAction.NavigationType == WKNavigationType.FormSubmitted)
       {
           //perform logic
       } 
   }
   ```

But then I don't know how to retrieve the response body from this variation of method. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had to implement this as well, I thought I'd post perhaps it may help others.

My use case is I need to inject an Authorization header to some request's which I managed to do with a fairly standard WKNavigationDelegate implementation. To do so I would cancel the existing request, create a copy and inject my altered headers then resubmit the request in the same browser which preserves cookies and existing connection properties. However some of the calls were failing and I have since found that POST's were not returning any body data.

This is how I got it working today;

```
public override async void DecidePolicy(WKWebView webView, WKNavigationAction navigationAction, Action<WKNavigationActionPolicy> decisionHandler)
        {  
            if (ShouldInjectAuthorizationHeader(navigationAction.Request))
            {
                decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.Cancel);
                webView.LoadRequest(await CreateRequestWithAuthorisationHeader(webView, navigationAction.Request));                
            }
            else
            {
                decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.Allow);
            }
        }
```

This is just to encapsulate the logic for the decide policy I am checking whether i need to modify the call or not.

ShouldInjectAuthorizationHeader above is just a check on the request.Url for whether it exists in a list of known urls and then I check the existing headers for whether the authorization is already present or not.

```
    private async Task<NSUrlRequest> CreateRequestWithAuthorisationHeader(WKWebView webView, NSUrlRequest request)
{
    var newRequest = (NSMutableUrlRequest)request.MutableCopy();
    newRequest.ShouldHandleCookies = request.ShouldHandleCookies;

    var requestModified = false;
    //This is not needed usually but i recheck here that i have an accesstoken to use and that the url requires it
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(AccessToken) == false && WebEx.DoesUrlMatchAnyPartial(request.Url.ToString(), InterceptUrls))
    {
        // inject the HTTP header
        var headers = request.Headers == null ? new NSMutableDictionary() : new NSMutableDictionary(request.Headers);
        headers.Add(new NSString("Authorization"), new NSString($"Bearer {AccessToken}"));

        newRequest.Headers = headers;
        if(request.HttpMethod == "POST")
        {
            try
            {
                //WKWebview has a 5 year running bug Apple https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=140188 
                //that the POST form data is not returned and not available so we run some custom javascript to serialise and expose it
                //then manually copy it over and set up the correct headers for it
                //Serilise form library from https://code.google.com/archive/p/form-serialize/
                var javascript = @"
function serialize(form){if(!form||form.nodeName!==""FORM""){return }var i,j,q=[];for(i=form.elements.length-1;i>=0;i=i-1){if(form.elements[i].name===""""){continue}switch(form.elements[i].nodeName){case""INPUT"":switch(form.elements[i].type){case""text"":case""hidden"":case""password"":case""button"":case""reset"":case""submit"":q.push(form.elements[i].name+""=""+encodeURIComponent(form.elements[i].value));break;case""checkbox"":case""radio"":if(form.elements[i].checked){q.push(form.elements[i].name+""=""+encodeURIComponent(form.elements[i].value))}break;case""file"":break}break;case""TEXTAREA"":q.push(form.elements[i].name+""=""+encodeURIComponent(form.elements[i].value));break;case""SELECT"":switch(form.elements[i].type){case""select-one"":q.push(form.elements[i].name+""=""+encodeURIComponent(form.elements[i].value));break;case""select-multiple"":for(j=form.elements[i].options.length-1;j>=0;j=j-1){if(form.elements[i].options[j].selected){q.push(form.elements[i].name+""=""+encodeURIComponent(form.elements[i].options[j].value))}}break}break;case""BUTTON"":switch(form.elements[i].type){case""reset"":case""submit"":case""button"":q.push(form.elements[i].name+""=""+encodeURIComponent(form.elements[i].value));break}break}}return q.join(""&"")};

serialize(document.querySelector('form'));";
                var result = await webView.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync(javascript);

                var data = result?.ToString();
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data) == false)
                {
                    newRequest.Body = data;
                    newRequest["Content-Length"] = $"{newRequest.Body.Length}";
                    newRequest["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                }
            }
            catch(NSErrorException ex)
            {
                Log.Error(ex, $"WKWebViewNavigationDelegate.CreateRequestWithAuthorisationHeader: JavaScript evaluation exception when trying to get Form post data, {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
        requestModified = true;
    }
    if (requestModified)
    {
        return newRequest;
    }
    return request;
}
```

I've simplified both methods above slightly for the post, removing debug output and cleaning up the variables but for the most part its as it runs in our system

> Looks like stack overflow doesnt like the double quoted minified js if
> you want to download that and reinsert it its from [minified js for
> extracting form data](https://code.google.com/archive/p/form-serialize/) I put that into a text editor and replaced all " with "" to allow it to parse inline in the @"" string

If you dont need the Authorization bearer stuff it will reduce alot of the code

Basically I pass the WKWebView to the method and run javascript in it to extract the form data when its a POST then copy it to a new request, cancel the old one with

```
decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.Cancel);
```

and redirect the webview with LoadRequest to a new MutableCopy of the original with extra headers and the POST data manually inserted

```
webView.LoadRequest(await CreateRequestWithAuthorisationHeader(webView, navigationAction.Request));
```

This seems to be working correctly now

For your requirement John you should be able to get the data very easily in your existing code with

```
public override void DecidePolicy(WKWebView webView, WKNavigationAction navigationAction, Action<WKNavigationActionPolicy>decisionHandler) 
{
    if (navigationAction.NavigationType == WKNavigationType.FormSubmitted)
    {
        //perform logic
var javascript = @"
function serialize(form){if(!form||form.nodeName!==""FORM""){return }var i,j,q=[];for(i=form.elements.length-1;i>=0;i=i-1){if(form.elements[i].name===""""){continue}switch(form.elements[i].nodeName){case""INPUT"":switch(form.elements[i].type){case""text"":case""hidden"":case""password"":case""button"":case""reset"":case""submit"":q.push(form.elements[i].name+""=""+encodeURIComponent(form.elements[i].value));break;case""checkbox"":case""radio"":if(form.elements[i].checked){q.push(form.elements[i].name+""=""+encodeURIComponent(form.elements[i].value))}break;case""file"":break}break;case""TEXTAREA"":q.push(form.elements[i].name+""=""+encodeURIComponent(form.elements[i].value));break;case""SELECT"":switch(form.elements[i].type){case""select-one"":q.push(form.elements[i].name+""=""+encodeURIComponent(form.elements[i].value));break;case""select-multiple"":for(j=form.elements[i].options.length-1;j>=0;j=j-1){if(form.elements[i].options[j].selected){q.push(form.elements[i].name+""=""+encodeURIComponent(form.elements[i].options[j].value))}}break}break;case""BUTTON"":switch(form.elements[i].type){case""reset"":case""submit"":case""button"":q.push(form.elements[i].name+""=""+encodeURIComponent(form.elements[i].value));break}break}}return q.join(""&"")};

serialize(document.querySelector('form'));";
                var result = await webView.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync(javascript);

                var data = result?.ToString();
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data) == false)
                {
/*
url encoded form data in data
You could replace the & with something else if you want it in a different format or try different javascript method, I found a few but I was after Url encoded so didn't experiment further, there were some alternatives that allowed for json format instead of url format
*/
}
    } 
}
```